# How do I know if I am handling the SHChangeNotify function correctly?

Tags: winapi

Following on from [How to rebuild Windows Icon Cache without closing explorer.exe or restarting Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799147/how-to-rebuild-windows-icon-cache-without-closing-explorer-exe-or-restarting-win) I need to know if I am using the `SHChangeNotify` function correctly.

In short, my requirement is to create and add a `desktop.ini` file to a folder from my Application, the `desktop.ini` file is used to let Windows know that the folder will be using a custom folder icon, the problem is the folder does not appear to update and show the new icon when it should be updated almost immediately.

The `desktop.ini` creation is very simple:

```
procedure TMainForm.MakeDesktopIni(FolderPath, IconPath: string);
var
  IniFile: TIniFile;
  Section: string;
begin
  IniFile := TIniFile.Create(IncludeTrailingBackslash(FolderPath) + 'desktop.ini');
  try
    Section := '.ShellClassInfo';
    IniFile.WriteInteger(Section, 'ConfirmFileOp', 0);
    IniFile.WriteInteger(Section, 'NoSharing', 1);
    IniFile.WriteString(Section, 'IconFile', IconPath);
    IniFile.WriteInteger(Section, 'IconIndex', 0);
  finally
    IniFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

As from the link posted above, the Folder Icon has definitely changed because viewing the Folder properties shows the new icon, but from Explorer it does not update to reflect this, at least not until explorer is restarted for example.

I have now tried in both Lazarus and Delphi the following with no success:

```
procedure RefreshFolderIcons(Folder: string);
begin
  {$IFDEF FPC}
    ShlObj.SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, SHCNF_PATH, PChar(Folder), nil);
  {$ELSE}
    Winapi.ShlObj.SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, SHCNF_PATH, PChar(Folder), nil);
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

If indeed that is the correct Windows function I need to call, I cannot understand why I am unable to get it to work from my Application?

Comment: I don't think you are meant to create this file. Do you have a reference that says you should?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan there are various places showing that creating the `desktop.ini` yourself is possible, here is one article showing this: [http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/customize-folder-icons-desktop-ini/](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/customize-folder-icons-desktop-ini/)

Comment: You don't seem to be setting the necessary attributes (`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM`) on the desktop.ini file.

Comment: Well, I'm thinking of an MSDN reference for programmatic manipulation. I don't regard that reference to be reliable.

Comment: @JonathanPotter sorry my mistake, I did infact set the file to be hidden and the folder icon does change, only not when I try to send the message to update it. I have not tried the system attribute however.

Comment: setting read-only, hidden and system attribute made no difference in regard to been able to refresh/update the folder, either I am calling the function wrong or something else is required. At this point I am not really much further forward, for days I have endlessly been trying a combination of several different things with no success, no matter what I try I cannot get Windows to show the new folder icon, it only changes when Windows decides to which could be several minutes later or after closing explorer.exe manually.

Comment: Maybe try the `SHCNF_FLUSH` flag as well?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this is the closest to an official article I could find: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)