# SHChangeNotify Not Always Working (C++) / Windows Icon Cache

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I've been trying to use SHChangeNotify to refresh Windows Explorer when an icon of an executable has changed.

My code currently changes the icon of multiple executables in a directory (via UpdateResource), and afterwards calls SHChangeNotify on the directory to refresh Explorer. I can confirm that the icon changes are successful - opening the executables in [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) shows that the icon resources have been successfully changed. However, calling SHChangeNotify only works some of the time, and exhibits strange behavior.

My call to SHChangeNotify looks like this:

`SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEDIR, SHCNF_PATH | SHCNF_FLUSH, directory_path, NULL);`

I have validated at runtime in a debugger that the directory path is correct.

Sometimes (maybe 1 in 10 times), the call works as expected. Most other times, nothing happens (i.e. icon doesn't update, even though the icon resource in the .exe has been changed, which is verified in Resource Hacker). However, after repeatedly changing an icon back and forth for testing purposes, things start to become strange. It will sometimes switch back and forth between old icons that are no longer being used. For example, the following is similar to a trace that I have occurred (suppose my program is called `change_and_refresh.exe`):

```
change_and_refresh.exe EXE RED_ICON     // icon changes to red
change_and_refresh.exe EXE BLUE_ICON     // icon changes to blue
change_and_refresh.exe EXE BLUE_ICON     // nothing happens
change_and_refresh.exe EXE BLUE_ICON     // nothing happens
change_and_refresh.exe EXE BLUE_ICON     // nothing happens
change_and_refresh.exe EXE BLUE_ICON     // icon changes to red - ??? 
change_and_refresh.exe EXE BLUE_ICON     // nothing happens
change_and_refresh.exe EXE BLUE_ICON     // icon changes to blue
```

I would imagine this is some sort of caching issue. Running the command `ie4uinit.exe -show`
(a command I found here that causes Windows to invalidate the icon cache, it seems) causes Explorer to refresh and show the correct item every time. E.g.:

```
change_and_refresh.exe EXE RED_ICON     // icon changes to red
change_and_refresh.exe EXE BLUE_ICON     // icon changes to blue
change_and_refresh.exe EXE RED_ICON     // nothing happens - FAILURE
ie4uinit.exe -show                      // icon changes to red
```

However, I don't really know anything about the internals of `ie4uinit.exe`. I tried looking at it with a decompiler but I'm not well-versed in reverse engineering - I did find a few calls to `SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEDIR, SHCNF_PATH, <some path>, NULL)`, but it is perhaps doing other things also.

Anyone know why these calls to SHChangeNotify are not working as expected? Is the OS ignoring them? I'm using the SHCNF_FLUSH flag so it seems like it should work straight away.

Information on specifically invalidating the icon cache (in general, or hopefully for specific icons/executables) would be helpful also.

Comment: Have you tried `SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED`, and/or `SHCNE_UPDATEITEM` for the exe itself? Have you tried using `SHCNF_IDLIST` instead of `SHCNF_PATH`?

Comment: Related/dupe: [How to rebuild Windows Icon Cache without closing explorer.exe or restarting Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799147/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Unfortunately, UPDATEITEM on the exe has the same issue. I avoided that at first because all changes are in the same directory, and I found this thread which suggested UPDATEDIR would be more [appropriate](https://microsoft.public.platformsdk.shell.narkive.com/yYo7cW05/multiple-shchangenotify-s-shell-ignores-most-of-them).

Comment: What's strange is that UPDATEITEM worked for a while (maybe the first 10 or so calls), then started having issues. I noticed similar with UPDATEDIR when I first tried it yesterday - maybe 10 calls worked before this behavior. It almost seems like the system is blocking this behavior...

Comment: ASSOCCHANGED does work, however! But this seems like a bit of an abuse of the call, as really no file association has changed. Put perhaps necessary to get this to work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you were modifying multiple exe's at a time.

Comment: Decompilation of `ie4uinit.exe` shows that it does use some `SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, ... )` calls, which perhaps is how that program achieves it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [`SHChangeNotify()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shchangenotify) documentation:

> Applications that register new handlers of any type must call SHChangeNotify with the SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED flag **to instruct the Shell to invalidate the icon and thumbnail cache**. This will also load new icon and thumbnail handlers that have been registered. Note, however, that icon overlay handlers are not reloaded.